# Box Topology Name

Tags: general-topology, terminology, math-history

To put it simply, why is the box topology on an infinite product of topological spaces called the box topology? What is "boxy" about it?

Comment: I always figured because the basis consists of "boxes", which I'm picturing as the Cartesian product of open intervals

Comment: @J.W.Tanner is correct: it is so called because its natural base is the set of all open boxes, i.e., all products of open sets in the factor spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we have a product $\prod_{a\in A}X_a$ of topological spaces $X_a$ for some index set $A$. Take open subsets $U_a\subseteq X_a$ for all $a\in A$. Then the "box" $\prod_{a\in A} U_a$ is open in the box topology (in fact, these sets form the standard basis for the box topology).

Think $X_a=\Bbb R$ with standard topology and $U_a$ being intervals, and the geometric analogy is complete.

Comment: note that the space could be a product of *uncountably* many components

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Very true. I'll fix.